# Problems when using ggplot aes_string, group, and linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have this data set:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000, 2, 5)
line.color <- sample(rep(1:4, 250))
line.type <- as.factor(sample(rep(1:5, 200)))

data <- data.frame(x, y, line.color, line.type)
```

I'm trying to plot the x and y variables group by the interaction of line.type and line.color. In addition I want to specify the linetype using line.type and the color using line.color. If I write this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = interaction(line.type, line.color), colour = line.color, linetype = line.type)) + geom_line()
```

It works but If I try to use aes_string like this:

```
interact <- c("line.color", "line.type")
inter <- paste0("interaction(", paste0('"', interact, '"', collapse = ", "), ")")

ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", group = inter, colour = "line.color", linetype = "line.type")) + geom_line()
```

I get the error:

```
Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to use aes_string because I have a lot of variables to plot.

Comment: Only x and y are strings, which is why ggplot2 is complaining. You should be able to use aes even if u have multiple plots.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by only x and y are strings? The grouping is also a string as suggested in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502263/ggplot-aes-string-with-interaction

Comment: I don't think `aes_string` works with a complicated string expression like `inter`, that you have here.

Comment: For example, you cant use `aes_string(x = "log(x)")`. It has to be a simple character string, not an expression that is evaluated.

Comment: Regardless, you shouldn't be relying on creating interaction variables on the fly within `aes()`. You should be creating them in your actual data frame.

Comment: @Ramnath Remarkably, it was Hadley that recommended the string parsing strategy, and it does appear to work, although I stand by my opinion that that is a pretty terrible way to go. The real problem here is just what the error says. Read it again.

Comment: @joran Mmm interesting. My hypothesis was based on the fact that the same piece of code works with `aes` and fails with `aes_string`. What else can explain that?

Comment: @Ramnath Wild guess: the `aes()` version is silently ignoring the interaction or line type and color? The group specification _should_ force dotted/dashed lines to contain multiple colors, but the graph doesn't seem to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there defining

```
inter <- paste0("interaction(", paste0('"', interact, '"', collapse = ", "), ")")
```

However, for `aes_string` to work, you need pass a character string of what would work if it you were calling `aes`, that is you don't need to have the arguments within `interaction` as strings. You want to create a string `"interaction(line.color, line.type)"`.   Therefore

```
 inter <- paste0('interaction(', paste0(interact, collapse = ', ' ),')')
 # or
 # inter <- sprintf('interaction(%s), paste0(interact, collapse = ', '))
 # the result being
 inter
 ## [1] "interaction(line.color, line.type)"

 # and the following works
 ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", 
    group = inter, colour = "line.color", linetype = "line.type")) + 
    geom_line()
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was mistaken on several counts in my comments above. This appears to work:

```
data$inter <- interaction(data$line.type,data$line.color)
ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", group = "inter",colour = "line.color",linetype = "line.type")) + geom_line()
```

(I was completely wrong about the graph specifying varying colour, etc within a single dashed/dotted line.)

I take this as a slight vindication, though, that relying on parsing of the `interaction` code inside `aes_string()` is a generally bad idea. My guess is that there is simply a small bug in ggplot's attempt to parse what you're giving `aes_string()` in complex cases that's causing it to evaluate things in an order that makes it look like you're asking for varying aesthetics over dashed/dotted lines.

Comment: Thanks, that works. It seems that aes_string can work with interaction specified as a complex string but it gets confused when I'm trying to specify the linetype.

Comment: @joran nice. I agree that it is always a good strategy to prep your data upfront before passing it to ggplot2. Despite ggplot2's ability to do data transformations on the fly, it is harder to debug, especially when you are dealing with complex transformations.