# ggplot aes_string does not work inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, parameter-passing

Using example given on this page: [ggplot inside function not working despite deparse(substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400689/ggplot-inside-function-not-working-despite-deparsesubstitute) , I tried to use aes_string but it is not working:

```
testfn <- function(gdf, first, second, third, fourth){
    print(
    ggplot(gdf, aes_string(first, second,
         color = fourth,
         linetype = third, 
         group = third:fourth))+
       geom_point()+
       geom_line() 
    )
}


> 
> testfn(phil, "Level", "value","Gender","Name")
Error in third:fourth : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In aes_string(first, second, color = fourth, linetype = third, group = third:fourth) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In aes_string(first, second, color = fourth, linetype = third, group = third:fourth) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
>
```

Where is the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a duplicate Q?

Comment: ggplot can't understand "third:fourth". if you're trying for interaction you need to do this (see Hadley's comment) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502263/ggplot-aes-string-with-interaction

Comment: and yes this seems very similar to the question you asked earlier? Thanks for pointing that out @BondedDust

Comment: Earlier question was for passing parameters to aes which was not working. Now I am trying to pass parameters to aes_string (though with the same data and function) and I am having problems. I am trying to follow the forum rules and giving all links. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: group = paste0("interaction(", paste0('"', third,":",fourth, '"', collapse = ", "), ")")))+   does not work. Error: attempt to apply non-function
In addition: Warning message:
In names(x)[!is.na(full)] <- .all_aesthetics[full[!is.na(full)]] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in `aes_string` you need to use names for `x` and `y` [compare `args(aes)` and `args(aes_string)`]. And then the interaction term can be formulated more understandably as `paste0("interaction(", third,", ",fourth, ")")`. So together this gives

```
testfn <- function(gdf, first, second, third, fourth){
  p <- ggplot(gdf, aes_string(x = first, 
                              y = second,
                              color = fourth,
                              linetype = third,
                              group = paste0("interaction(", third,", ",fourth, ")"))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() 
  print(p)
}
testfn(phil, "Level", "value","Gender","Name")
```